# How do I pass an array to a class witch is under the influence of keys as a parameter? ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hi if I try to pass an array to a class function as a parameter it workes fine.
try it in this snippet of code:

```js
class boo {
    moo() {
        this.bob = [false, "Bob"];
        this.kees = [false, "Kees"];
    }

    doo() {
        this.bob = [true, "Bob"];
        this.kees = [true, "Kees"];
    }
}

class foo {
    constructor() {
        this.hi = [];
    }
    lala(arg) {
        let bool = arg[0];
        let string = arg[1];
        if (bool && !this.hi[string]) {
            this.hi[string] = true;
            return string + " is true"
        }
        return string + " is true - will be entered one time not multiple";
    }

    dada(arg) {
        let bool = arg[0];
        let string = arg[1];
        if (!bool && this.hi[string]) {
            this.hi[string] = false;
            return string + " is false";
        }
        return string + " is false - will be entered one time not multiple";
    }
}

objBoo = new boo();
objFoo = new foo();

objBoo.doo();
console.log(objFoo.lala(objBoo.bob));
console.log(objFoo.lala(objBoo.bob));
console.log(objFoo.lala(objBoo.kees));
objBoo.moo();
console.log(objFoo.dada(objBoo.bob));
console.log(objFoo.dada(objBoo.kees));
console.log(objFoo.dada(objBoo.kees));
```

So what is the problem in this code snippet? I can not figure it out by my self. I feel like it has something to do with this question: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

```js
/*ignore pls*/class BehaviourClass {
/*ignore pls*/    constructor() {
/*ignore pls*/        this.start = true;
/*ignore pls*/    }
/*ignore pls*/
/*ignore pls*/    Awake() {
/*ignore pls*/        window.AnimationFrame();
/*ignore pls*/    }
/*ignore pls*/}

//like the boo class where it works fine;
class KeyCodeClass {
    KeyDown(e) {
        //spacebar
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { this.Space = [true, "Space"] }
    }

    KeyUp(e) {
        //spacebar
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { this.Space = [false, "Space"] }
    }
}

//like the foo class where it works fine
class InputClass {
    constructor() {
        this.pressed = [];
    }

    GetKeyDown(arg) {
        let bool = arg[0];
        let string = arg[1];
        if (bool && !this.pressed[string]) {
            this.pressed[string] = true;
            return true;
        }
        if (!bool && this.pressed[string]) {
            this.pressed[string] = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

    GetKeyUp(arg) {
        let bool = arg[0];
        let string = arg[1];
        if (bool && !this.pressed[string]) {
            this.pressed[string] = true;
            return false;
        }
        if (!bool && this.pressed[string]) {
            this.pressed[string] = false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

/*ignore pls*/var Behaviour = new BehaviourClass();
var KeyCode = new KeyCodeClass();
var Input = new InputClass();

//controles if a key is pressed
window.addEventListener("keydown", KeyCode.KeyDown.bind(KeyCode), false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", KeyCode.KeyUp.bind(KeyCode), false);

/*ignore pls*/function AnimationFrame() {
/*ignore pls*/    Update();
/*ignore pls*/    requestAnimationFrame(AnimationFrame);
/*ignore pls*/}

function Update() {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        console.log("spacebar down");
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) {
        console.log("spacebar up");
    }
}

/*ignore pls*/Behaviour.Awake();
```

I get the error arg is undefined by the second snippet. But in the class foo from the first snippet works fine. Can someone explain what I do wrong.
The snippets are in my opinion almost the same.

Comment: Could you kindly rewrite the question title in English?

Comment: What's an "invulensed bij key"?

Comment: @DaveNewton I chance the value KeyCode.Space by pressing the spacebar in that way invulensed bij key.

Comment: @RensvWalstijn I was mostly asking what the words "invulensed" and "bij" meant; I think there's a translation issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton "under the influence of keys" I will edit the question I read "bij" I undersrand the translation issue thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyCode.Space` is not defined in your code, so the value of `KeyCode.Space` is `undefined`  and when you call the function `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` the argument is passed as undefined.

Next, in the function `GetKeyDown(arg)`, the arg would be undefined and when you are trying to find the element at 0th index by using the statement `let bool = arg[0];` it throws an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

So, define the value for the `KeyCode.Space` in your code and also write the gaurd condition before proceeding ahead in the function. If the condition fails, then return.

Comment: Oh thanks! I need to use the constructor and devinde `this.Space = [];` To long looking at the problem -,-